# Make an image smooth and then revert back to original image

Tags: php, algorithm, image-processing, gd, smoothing

I am now writing a program in PHP to make an image smooth.

I used some of the methods from wikipedia on [smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing).

They introduce [few algorithms to make an image smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing#Smoothing_algorithms).

However, I could not find a method that is also reversible, i.e. I could not go back from the smooth image to the original image.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make a copy of the initial image...

Comment: search for deconvolution

Comment: Unfortunately, image smoothing is in general an irreversible process.

Comment: Most of these algorithms smooths the images by aproximating some aspect of the image. Others uses the color of the neighbor pixels (kernel). In most of these processes information are lost, therefore it is impossible to go back. For instance, it is impossible to recover an image to its original state after a Gaussian blur since the value of the pixels of the processed image is the combination of its neighbors and there are many combinations that give the same value to that pixel. What exactly are you trying to do?